# OnLocationChanged triggered on different interval on different devices

Tags: android, xamarin

Trying to get location in a time specified in requestLocationUpdate . But OnLocationChanged event invoked on different time interval on different devices

INITIALIZE LOCATION MANAGER

```
      private void InitializeLocationManager()
      {      
            latlon.provider = new List<string>();
            _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
            //Application criteria for selecting provider
            Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria { Accuracy = Accuracy.NoRequirement };
            IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);


            if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
            {
                _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
            }
            else
            {
                _locationProvider = String.Empty;
            }

            if (_locationProvider != null && _locationProvider != string.Empty)
            {
                   //Request for gps in 10sec and 0 distance travelled 
                    _locationManager.RequestLocationUpdates(_locationProvider, 10000, 0, 
             }
       }
```

LOCATION LISTENER INTERFACE

```
    async public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        try
        {
            _currentLocation = location;
            if (_currentLocation == null)
            {
            }

            else
            {
                 Android.Util.Log.Info("GetLocation", "Latitude: " + _currentLocation.Latitude.ToString() + "        Longitude: " + _currentLocation.Longitude.ToString());

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeLocationManager();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeLocationManager();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }
    }

    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "status Changed", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

Implementing in Xamarin.android
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Documentation: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

It says

> minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds

`Minimum time` is not `exact time` between location updates. So do not rely on this value.